# i cannot delete rows in my master view controller

Tags: ios

cannot delete the rows, am getting terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object

i have the following:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class CSDetailViewController;
@interface CSMasterViewController : UITableViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) CSDetailViewController *detailViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *kryeministrat;
@end
```

and the following at implementation:

```
#import "CSMasterViewController.h"
#import "CSDetailViewController.h"

@implementation CSMasterViewController    
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
[super awakeFromNib];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"KryeministratList" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *kryeministratInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
self.kryeministrat = [kryeministratInfo objectForKey:@"kryeministrat"];
self.detailViewController = (CSDetailViewController *)   [[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
}
#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.kryeministrat count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDictionary *kryeministrat = self.kryeministrat[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = kryeministrat[@"name"];
return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSDictionary *kryeministrat = self.kryeministrat[indexPath.row];
NSString *urlString = kryeministrat[@"url"];
self.detailViewController.detailItem = urlString;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
 forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[self.kryeministrat removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your exception, you should look into this code:

```
NSDictionary *kryeministratInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
self.kryeministrat = [kryeministratInfo objectForKey:@"kryeministrat"];
```

Although property `kryeministrat` is declared as  `NSMutableArray` , `kryeministratInfo` is `NSDictionary`. It means the values in the `kryeministratInfo` are all immutable.

SO you can do like:

```
NSDictionary *kryeministratInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
self.kryeministrat = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[kryeministratInfo objectForKey:@"kryeministrat"]];
```